# Incorrect 'if' statement caused erroneous results

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement, boolean-expression

In the debugger I've verified that movementAmount is equal to 1 when it is supposed to be, yet when I get to the if statement in the class it executes the second if statement which requires movementAmount to be 10.

My Point object, position, ends up being plus one extra as well so the Y coordinate is turning out to be 11 and not 10, I think that may be part of the problem.

Class:

```
public partial class Robot
{
    public string direction = "north";
    private Point position = new Point(0, 0);
    private int movementAmount = 1;

    public Robot() {}

    public void moveRobot()
    {
        if (direction == "north" || direction == "North" & movementAmount == 1)
        {
            position.Y += movementAmount;
        }
        if (direction == "north" || direction == "North" & movementAmount == 10)
        {
            position.Y += movementAmount;
        }
        if (direction == "east" || direction == "East" & movementAmount == 1)
        {
            position.X += movementAmount;
        }
        if (direction == "east" || direction == "East" & movementAmount == 10)
        {
            position.X += movementAmount;
        }
        if (direction == "south" || direction == "South" & movementAmount == 1)
        {
            position.Y -= movementAmount;
        }
        if (direction == "south" || direction == "South" & movementAmount == 10)
        {
            position.Y -= movementAmount;
        }
        if (direction == "west" || direction == "West" & movementAmount == 1)
        {
            position.X -= movementAmount;
        }
        if (direction == "west" || direction == "West" & movementAmount == 10)
        {
            position.X -= movementAmount;
        }
    }

    public Point Position
    {
        get
        {
            return position;
        }
    }

    public int MovementAmount
    {
        get
        {
            return movementAmount;
        }
        set
        {
            movementAmount = value;
            if (movementAmount != 1 & movementAmount != 10)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Must be 1 or 10");
            }
        }
    }
 }

}
```

Main program:

```
public partial class frmSimpleRobot : Form
{
    public frmSimpleRobot()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Robot arrow = new Robot();

    private void btnGoOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        arrow.MovementAmount = 1;
    }

    private void btnGoTen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        arrow.MovementAmount = 10;
    }

    private void btnNorth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        arrow.direction = "north";
        arrow.moveRobot();
        lblRobotPos.Text = "(X=" + arrow.Position.X.ToString() + ", " + "Y=" + arrow.Position.Y.ToString() + ")";
    }

    private void btnEast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        arrow.direction = "east";
        arrow.moveRobot();
        lblRobotPos.Text = "(X=" + arrow.Position.X.ToString() + ", " + "Y=" + arrow.Position.Y.ToString() + ")";
    }

    private void btnSouth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        arrow.direction = "south";
        arrow.moveRobot();
        lblRobotPos.Text = "(X=" + arrow.Position.X.ToString() + ", " + "Y=" + arrow.Position.Y.ToString() + ")";
    }

    private void btnWest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        arrow.direction = "west";
        arrow.moveRobot();
        lblRobotPos.Text = "(X=" + arrow.Position.X.ToString() + ", " + "Y=" + arrow.Position.Y.ToString() + ")";
    }


}
```

}

Assistance please?

Comment: When `direction == "north"`, the value of `movementAmount` won't matter much. Use `()`

Comment: @AlexBell: How can both `direction == "north"` **and** `direction == "North"` ever be true?

Comment: The best way is to use either 'else if', or 'switch' statement as posted below. Regards,

Comment: You combine [bitwise `&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/sbf85k1c.aspx) with logical `||`. By intention? Doesn't look so.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Never, but `North || north` should be no issue. ;-)

Comment: @JensG: `&` is *not* a "bitwise" operator when applied to `bool` values. For `bool` values, it is a logical *and* without shortcut evaluation. You already linked to the relevant documentation.

Comment: Correct. Shouldn't switch so much between languages, I guess. Irritating anyway to mix || and &

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have put the `||` expressions in parentheses. The `&` operator (and the `&&` operator, which is what you actually should have used) has higher precedence, so as long as the direction string matched, the whole expression was true.

That said, that code is just crazy (no offense intended :) ). It's hard to read, inefficient, and prone to bugs (your question case in point). Try something like this instead:

```
public void moveRobot()
{
    switch (direction)
    {
    case "north":
    case "North":
        position.Y += movementAmount;
        break;
    case "east":
    case "East":
        position.X += movementAmount;
        break;
    case "south":
    case "South":
        position.Y -= movementAmount;
        break;
    case "west":
    case "West":
        position.X -= movementAmount;
        break;
    }
}
```

Even better would be to make `direction` an `enum` instead of a `string`, to ensure you always get a valid value.

Comment: `switch (direction.ToLower())` ?

Comment: The above is more consistent with the OP's original code. Note that if you were to use lower-case, you'd want to call `direction.ToLowerInvariant()`. But it's wasteful, as it (relatively expensively) creates a new `string` instance just for the purpose of the comparison, when the `switch` statement can handle the options just fine. Also, calling `ToLower()` would allow things like "NoRTH", etc. when the original code did not. Whether that's reasonable cannot be determined from the given code. Using an `enum` (which I proposed) would render the whole question moot.

Comment: use of enum definitely better as you stated always a valid value.

Comment: I agree with `enums`. Strings are slow and more prone to error.